# How to authenticate Rails API without username and password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authentication, rails-api

I understand with a Rails API, or any REST API, a user will send a username and password, the server will confirm the user is valid, and returns a HTTP token for future requests to the API to be valid.

I'm creating an API with Rails that will be communicating to a script that a user can paste in the header of their site. My Rails API will therefore not be getting a username or password, just a site id, to know if the API should be used.

My questions is: **how can you authenticate an API when username and password are not being used?** I could check that the domain the the request is coming from matches the site id and then send a token, but it does not seem totally secure as anyone with the site id and knowledge of changing the request headers origin could access the API.

Comment: If your API is called from client side (e.g. script) it can't be secured, the information will be available to everyone, your solution will add some security though. If you want "totally secure" you must call your API on the backend.

Comment: @Gerry thanks for the clarification, this is what I presumed. Would this be true for something like Google Analytics as well?

Comment: I think it will be enough for the average site, but if you handle sensitive information then definetly not.

Comment: Yes, and the protection used by Google Analytics (if you set it up) is also done by matching the site hostname. But keep in mind that analytics is not used for sensitive data.